# Notepad++ - RegEx - Number and Date

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following text in NotePad++, I am trying to write a RegEx to find and replace with the following.

```
Find: #,##/ (Look for the pattern 2,10/)
Replace: #\r (at the comma replace with a new line, so the date starts on a new line)



 11/02/2016,18,54,61,13,37,05,2,10/29/2016,42,48,20,21,19,23,3,10/26/2016,48,56,02,16,03,24,2,10/22/2016,01,55,33,28,56,22,2,10/19/2016,43,63,16,38,10,23,2,10/15/2016,64,49,57,23,67,20,2,10/12/2016,34,44,30,16,37,16,2,
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for capturing groups: capture the different parts that should get split with a newline and use backreferences in the replacement pattern.

*Search*: `(\d,)(\d+/)` 
*Replace*: `$1\n$2`

See the NPP screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The search term should be something like this `(\d,)(\d+\/)`. The `/` character should be escaped.

Comment: @AlphaQ: The `/` char is not a special regex character and should not be escaped. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/CbX8Y3/1) at regex101.com.

Comment: @AlphaQ: What good checking the functionality of a *Boost* regex in an online tester that only supports *JavaScript* regex flavor? JS does not require escaping a `/` inside constructor notation, try `console.log(new RegExp("/api/").test("some/api/here"))` in your console. Why? **Because the `/` is not a special regex metacharacter.**

Comment: probably exclude the comma from the capture part ?

Comment: @Skycc: That is a good idea if OP needs to remove the comma at the end of the line. The question is not 100% clear about that. `(\d),(\d+/)` would remove them.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work: `(\d),(\d\d/)`

Replace with: `\1\r\2`

Result example:

[image: After "Replace All"]